# Can I use vuelidate to validate "any kind of data", e.g. non-Vue, non-form data?

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate

We're already using [Vuelidate - a Vue.js model validation library](https://vuelidate.netlify.com/) to validate "configuration" for a "widget" in an "Edit Widget Configuration" form.

Now we also need to determine whether a "configuration" object (e.g. from JSON) it is valid, without the "configuration" object being inside a Vue object like a form, and would like to re-use the validation logic we've already written for the form.

Can I use vuelidate to validate such a non-vue "configuration" Javascript object? If so, how?

The question stems from a [forum.vuejs.org post](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/does-vuelidate-generate-error-messages/35544/2), where "wube" says:

> I think you missed the purpose of Vuelidate. This is just a model-based validation library. Its goal is to give you an information whether the data is valid or not. I think that you probably got confused because all the examples in their docs are based on forms, but Vualidate can be used to validate any kind of data, not only forms data (in opposite to libraries like Parsley 43 that are designed for forms validation).

Exaclty. I'm trying to validate "any kind of data". How can I do that?

So how do I create the `$v` from:

```
let configuration = {
  name: '',
  age: 0
};

let validations = {
  name: {
    required,
    minLength: minLength(4)
  },
  age: {
    between: between(20, 30)
  }
};

let $v = ???
```